# Hiding a custom option on a product in Magento

Tags: php, sql, database, magento, e-commerce

I have several hundred products in my Magento store, all of which have a very similar set of custom options.  I used one product as a template, and copied its custom options to all of the other products so that all of the products currently have the same set of custom options.

I would like to disable or hide certain custom options for some products in my store without deleting the option completely.  Right now, I only have the ability to delete an option for a product entirely. For example, some products cannot currently be ordered in different colors, but they might be later; I'd like to be able to disable the color option rather than delete it and re-add the entire list of colors later.

Does anyone have any similar experience who can provide me with some help with this problem?  Thanks, I really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using custom options for attributes like "color" is not a correct approach for Magento. Magento has special product type - **Configurable** product for the catalog structure you're trying to achieve.

Here's benefits you'll get from using configurable product instead of custom options:

1. Automatic stock management. You won't need to enable-disable your custom options as soon as some physical item is out of stock - Magento will do it for you.
2. You won't have to copy all custom options to a new product you create. The attribute for the *Attribute set* this product belongs to will automatically be available for new entries.
3. You will have ability to filter your products by the **color** attribute on Category page using Layered Navigation.

Here's the [guide how to create configurable product](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-creating-a-configurable-product) from the official Magento wiki.

Comment: Thank you for your help!  Unfortunately, "color" was only a simplified example I used for the sake of clarity.  In my case, I'll actually be using custom options that allow customers to include things like extra sets of keys, different types of locks, caster bases or wheels, etc.  Sorry for confusing the context of my question like I did.  With that in mind, do you have any advice regarding my original problem?  Thanks again for taking the time to help me, it is very appreciated